# Monitor all subfolder by file-endpoint in Mule

Tags: mule

If we use a file-endpoint in Mule 3.3.1, is there any possibility to monitor(polling) all subfolders in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly no I don't think so (although there may be good performance reasons for this to be so).

I'd guess that you would have to extend and alter the `FileConnector`'s `createReceiver()` method to make this possible.

Cheers,